# A.M./P.M. localization (AMDesignator, PMDesignator)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to localize A.M. & P.M. in datetime in C#.

How reliable is it to use values returned by C#'s 'PMDesignator' & 'AMDesignator' (as in the code below) ?

How can I handle both the below scenarios using the same code?

```
                                                                        //Line# Output
                                                                        //----- ------
void Main()                                                             //1
{                                                                       //2
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; // it is 5:56 PM now                    //3 it is 5:56 PM now   
                                                                        //4
    //Japanese                                                          //5
    var JapaneseCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ja");   //6 
    Console.WriteLine(JapaneseCulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator);     //7     午後
    Console.WriteLine(JapaneseCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator);     //8     午前
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("t",JapaneseCulture));                //9     17:56
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("hh:mm tt",JapaneseCulture));         //10    05:56 午後
                                                                        //11
    //German                                                            //12
    var GermanCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de");     //13    
    Console.WriteLine(GermanCulture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator);       //14    (blank)
    Console.WriteLine(GermanCulture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator);       //15    (blank)
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("t",GermanCulture));                  //16    17:56
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("hh:mm tt",GermanCulture));           //17    05:56
}
```

Japanese - 
PMDesignator, AMDesignator have values,
but are not shown in Line 9 when using "t".
In this case the format specified in Line 10 ("hh:mm tt") gives more correct output.

German - 
PMDesignator, AMDesignator don't have values, 
so using "t" as in Line 16 gives the correct output,
while Line 17 which uses "hh:mm tt" gives incorrect output.

[EDIT: After reading comments:]
Does "t" give the "typically" used formats fairly reliably? (I have no prior experience in localization, so I do not have a good idea of how reliable the values are)

Comment: If you localize dates, you should also localize the format string. When using an appropriate format string for Germany, you won't need an AM/PM designator, because we use hours between 0 and 24, not 1 and 12.

Comment: Why do you think `hh:mm tt" is more correct than "t" for japanese?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - can you elaborate on how to localize the format string. About 'hh:mm tt' being more correct - for Japanese, PMDesignator & AMDesignator have values, so in my case, I would like to see those values being used (instead of showing military time i.e. 24 hour format). (For Japanese, I am assuming both formats are correct.).

Comment: From growing up in Japan, I know that Japanese typically use 24-hour time, making the AM/PM designator superfluous. So I think it's actually doing the *right* thing here.

Comment: @JeffBridgman - I am looking for a similar answer for all languages - whether "t" gives the "typically" used formats fairly reliably. (I have no prior experience in localization, so I do not have a good idea of how reliable the values are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) in .NET will do the correct thing for the user's culture. In your case just use:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("ja");
var dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("t", culture)); // t => Short Time format.
```

Only override the culture-specific format with [customizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) if *really* required by a specific business requirement.

Microsoft throws a lot of money at their localization efforts to ensure that formatting, translations, etc. are correct for everyone.