# Why does "DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de"))" return different results in different versions of .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, .net-5

I'm fairly confused. Having read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13391774/16607977) that we should rely on the built-in localization, I was surprised by the following observation:

When I run

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de")));
    }
}
```

I'm getting very different results depending on the framework and/or compiler. Example is based on 10:00 UTC (10 AM).

- Running it on [try-dotnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet) I get: `10 vorm.`
- Running it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) with "compiler" set to .NET 5 I get the same: `10 vorm.`

Now the fun part:

- Running it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) with "compiler" set to .NET 4.7.2 I get: `10`
- Running it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) with "compiler" set to *Roslyn* I get: `10`

And it gets weirder: I've tried it locally with a console app and expanded the example to

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de")));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de-DE")));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("fr")));
```

These are the results - with try-dotnet added for comparison.

| Culture | .NET 5 | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 2.0 | .NET Framework 4.8 | Mono | try-dotnet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "de" | 10 AM | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 vorm. | 10 vorm. |
| "de-DE" | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 vorm. | 10 vorm. |
| "fr" | 10 AM | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 AM | 10 AM |

In the Mono column, the results are from compiling the file with Mono (*Mono JIT compiler version 6.4.0*), then running it with mono. Running the .exe without Mono yields the same results as the third column.

Where is this coming from, is it a bug in the compiler or the framework? Is it just broken or is this somehow by design?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet! Would you happen to know why "de-DE" is still printed as "10" even on .NET 5? And where would I file a change request, I still don't understand what layer is responsible. Is it Windows, is it .NET?

Comment: @badasta: I would assume it's the data within ICU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This breaking change is a result of [the use of the ICU Libraries on Windows instead of the NLS Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api).

You can verify this in a .net 5.0 application by adding the following to the project to revert from using the ICU libraries back to using the NLS ones:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After adding that to my test .Net 5.0 console app with the code

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de")));
```

The output changes from `11 AM` to `11` (at the time of writing).

[See here for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu).

Comment: Ah, this explains a lot. Do have any idea why dotnet-try seems to show the Mono-behaviour?

Comment: Sorry no idea about dotnet-trt, but perhaps it's hosted on an older Windows platform (maybe via Docker).

Comment: But why would it output "11" for "de-DE" even with .NET 5, while for "de" it's "11 AM"?

Comment: @badasta Possibly because "de-DE" defines a locale which does not use am/pm indicator (and thus omits it) whereas "de" doesn't define such a locale. I expect the answer is buried somewhere in [the ICU unicode site](https://icu.unicode.org/) (The "DE" part is the country, whereas "de" is the language, and of course formats can differ by country; think of "en-GB" versus "en-US". The former uses dd/mm/yyyy and the latter mm/dd/yyyy. Just specifying "en" results in mm/dd/yyyy.)