# Datetime.ToString adds dot to month abbreviation in .NET6

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-6.0

I have this simple code sample in C#. It creates a filename voor an invoice:

```
var x = new DateTime(2022,8,26);
var invoiceNumber = 1100;

var fileName = "CustomerX-Invoice";
    fileName += $"-{invoiceNumber}";
    fileName += $"-{x.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"))}";

Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

This was working fine in .NET Core 3.1. It returns a filename 'CustomerX-Invoice-1100-26-aug-2022'.

After migrating to .NET6 it's suddenly adding a dot to the abbreviation of the month. It's now returning 'CustomerX-Invoice-1100-26-aug.-2022'. See the dot after 'aug'.

When I test it in LINQPad7 I see the problem is introduced in .NET5 already. I can't find out if this is by design or a known bug? It could be an issue with the culture 'nl-NL' also? When I for example change it to 'en-US' no dot is added to the month abbreviation.

Linqpad sample using .NET Core 3.1:
[image: It's working fine in .NET Core 3.1]

Linqpad sample using .NET6:

[image: In .NET6 a dot is added]

Of course I can manipulate the string and remove the dot but I would rather see I can trust .NET to return the month abbreviation without the dot.

Any suggestions on what's happening here and how handle this the best way?

Comment: This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345101/why-does-datetime-now-tostringhh-tt-new-cultureinfode-return-differen

Comment: I just tested with CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))}"; its okay

Comment: This is a product of your CultureInfo, are you required to use that?

Comment: We need to use the Dutch abbreviations so using 'en-US' or InvariantCulture wouldn't help us. String manipulation is really ugly. But does this mean that with introcution from .NET5 they decided to add a dot for the culture nl-NL specific?

Comment: .net 6 has it correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_Netherlands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt", new CultureInfo("de"))" return different results in different versions of .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345101/why-does-datetime-now-tostringhh-tt-new-cultureinfode-return-differen)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the rules of the nl-NL culture format. You will want to change or remove your culture target or do some basic string manipulation to remove the ".".

If this is for internal use in your program and is not shown to the user, you can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to get a consistent output every time without any localization. I recommend using this Culture for all backend work.

```cs
var x = new DateTime(2022, 8, 26);
var invoiceNumber = 1100;

var fileName = "CustomerX-Invoice";
fileName += $"-{invoiceNumber}";
fileName += $"-{x.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";

Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```